# Save a selection from Holoview Points as CSV

Tags: python, export-to-csv, holoviews, datashader

This is a part of my code:

```
filtered_df = data.loc[data["ini_sin"].between(str(self.inicio), str(self.final))]
points = hv.Points(filtered_df, kdims= 
             ['x','y'],vdims['no_caso','dir_est','edad','sexo','semana','ini_sin','depto','muni']
points = points.select(edad = self.edad_s)
points = points.select(edad = self.semana_s)
```

I need to pass from the selection of points(hv.Points) to csv , and later download the csv file.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Holoviews is a visualization library, so it's a bit unusual to try to export a holoviews object to csv. Any reason you can't just do the same operation in pandas with filtered_df? If not, I *think* a holoviews Points object is a wrapped version of an `xarray.DataArray`? If so, you could try `points.to_series()` to get the data back into pandas and then reshape and export to CSV from there...

Comment: Part of the reason you're not getting many answers is because it's really hard for us to reproduce the issue without your data, and you haven't even showed us what filtered_df or points looks like. Check out this guide to creating a [mre] and this one for [crafting minimal bug reports](https://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2018/02/28/minimal-bug-reports) - they provide really helpful guidance on how to structure a question so you're most likely to get a useful answer. Good luck!